# Definition of triangle

Tags: definition, triangles

If a polygon has 3 sides, but one side has zero length (or one angle is zero degree), is it still a triangle by definition of triangle?

and how about if it has 2 sides, if not 3 sides are zero?

Comment: Some people call it a degenerate triangle. I hope its feelings are not hurt.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Not if you reassure it that it's not at all obtuse, and it's still a-cute triangle.

Comment: How could two sides be zero, and not the third? It doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality.